# Finding the appropriate Linear Transformation given input and output points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm trying to solve this problem about finding the right Linear Transformation $\phi: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ which maps a set of 3 given points 
$A=(x_A, y_A) \space \space B=(x_B, y_B) \space \space C=(x_C, y_C) \space$
to 3 other given points $ A'=(x_{A'}, y_{A'}) \space B'=(x_{B'}, y_{B'}) \space C'=(x_{C'}, y_{C'})$ respectively.

My first idea was to check whether 2 of those vectors were a basis for $\mathbb{R^2}$ and express the other one as a linear combination like this:

$(x',y')=\alpha(x_A,y_A)+\beta(x_B,y_B)+\gamma(x_C,y_C)$

and then I can find $\alpha, \space \beta, \space \gamma$.

I'm not sure how to proceed from here, would there be a better approach?

Comment: What were you planning to do with these scalars once you found them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have more than two points, you can also consider for
\begin{equation}
T = \begin{pmatrix}
T_{11} & T_{12}\\
T_{21} & T_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
the problem 
\begin{equation}
\min_{T} \|XT-X'\|_F^2
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
X = \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & y_1\\
x_2 & y_2\\
x_3 & y_3
\end{pmatrix},\quad X' = \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 '& y_1'\\
x_2' & y_2'\\
x_3' & y_3'
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
This may look too difficult, but we have the closed-form expression for the minimizer (assuming $X$ is of sufficient rank):
\begin{equation}
T^{\star}=(X^{\top}X)^{-1}X^{\top}X'
\end{equation}
which is your desired transformation. Note that for more than two points a transformation which does the trick ***exactly***, might simply not exist.

Comment: Interesting, does the transformation not exist if $(X^TX)^{-1}$ does not exist?

Comment: In that case you find $T^{\star}$ indeed, but it might be the case the map $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ you are looking for does not exist. Remember, this is a least-squares approach.

Answer (score 1):

A linear transformation $$T:\mathbb {R^2} \to \mathbb {R^2}$$ is determined by a $2\times 2$ matrix $$M = \begin {bmatrix} a &b\\c&d\end {bmatrix}$$

To find such a matrix all you need is two points on the plane with their images.

If $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ map to $(u_1,v_1)$ and $(u_2, v_2)$ respectively, then we solve the sustem

$$ ax_1+by_1 =u_1,  cx_1+dy_1 =u_2, ax_2+by_2 =u_2,  cx_2+dy_2 =v_2$$

for $a,b,c,d$ and the transformation is simply $$ T(x,y) = M\binom {x}{y}$$

Comment: To be precise, you need two *linearly independent* points and there images to completely determine the map.

Comment: Correct. We need to be able to solve the system.