# Checking if a linear transformation contains a shear

Tags: matrices, geometry, linear-transformations

I am using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838849/finding-the-appropriate-linear-transformation-given-input-and-output-points) approach, from a previous question when trying to extract the transformation matrix from one set of points to another. The main difference is that I use homogenous coordinates. For example, consider I have the following set of points: $(1,1), (1,3), (2,1)$ and $(1,1), (5,1), (5,3)$

Hence, I have
$$
X=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 3 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
X'=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
5 & 1 & 1\\
5 & 3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

When I put this into the equation from the link I obtain my transformation matrix $T$ as:

$$
T=
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 2 & 0\\
2 & 0 & 0\\
-5 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

My question is how can I check whether or not the transformation includes a shear?

**EDIT**

I can assume uniform scaling.

Based on the fact that I can assume uniform scaling and [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/74527/how-do-i-disassemble-a-3x3-transformation-matrix-into-rotation-and-scaling-matri) question, is it a matter of checking if the length of the leftmost column vectors are the same? (after extracting the translation components?)

Comment: It might be helpful if you could add what you mean by a 'shear'.

Comment: @Jeremy Jeffrey James a shear skews the function

Comment: The question is not clear. Have you rotated or translated the points through those matrices? Which points are transforming to what?

Comment: You can't distinguish shear and non-uniform scaling.

Comment: A transformation is shear-free if it preserves orthogonality (only the linear coefficients matter, ignore the affine ones). Clearly, $(4,2)$ and $(2,0)$ aren't orthogonal.

Comment: @SnipingPoodle I have my first set of points (1,1),(1,3),(2,1)  and my second set of points (1,1),(5,1),(5,3). I am trying to find what transformation maps (1,1) from the first set to the (1,1) in the second set, while also transforming the (1,3) in the first set to the (5,1) in the second, and (2,1) into (5,3). I don't have access to what the transformation is made out of - I am trying to find that out

Comment: @IAmAGuest I have added an edit clarifying that i can indeed assume uniform scaling

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping

Comment: @Bula: no, if your matrix is skewed, uniform scaling does not make sense. The scale will depend on the direction.

Comment: Your "I can assume uniform scaling" clarification was needed, but is still confusingly worded, as @user958916 points out.  Suggestion: change the wording of the overall question to "Checking if a linear transformation contains a shear or nonuniform scaling".  Assuming that's what you mean, you can test that by checking whether the matrix times its transpose is (not) a multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: And, yes, that's equivalent to whether, after discarding the translation (homogeneous) part, the remaining column vectors (or, equivalently, row vectors) are pairwise orthogonal and all have the same magnitudes.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring any translation, your transformation applies the unit vector $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ to $(4\cos\theta+2\sin\theta,2\cos\theta)$. The latter does not have a constant length.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not sure how to interpret this? Would a non-constant length imply a shear ?

Comment: Shear and stretch occur simultaneously.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you function is skewed (shear) although I cannot pin-point it in your matrix.

Your original point points map onto a cartesian plane something like this:
[image: Original Points]

Your transformed points look something like this:
[image: Transformed Points]

If your points all follow a singular, **same transformation** for all of them, then they could be considered as a whole:

[image: Triangles]

In the above image, the green triangle is being transformed to the red one. The triangle is in picture above proves that the triangular plane is being stretched as one of the points remains the same while the others change, meaning it has to sheared.

Another way to prove that your graph is sheared:
You can see that for $y = 1$, it is transformed to $y = 1$ in your first point, but also to $y = 3$ in your third point. This is physically not possible with just one linear equation for both points at once.

Finding the shear transformation:
I do not know how to find it in 3x3 matrix but using a 2x2 matrix a function can be sheared by apply the following matrix transformation:

$$T \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & m \\ k & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$$

,where, $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & m \\ k & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ is the shear transformation ( m = horizontal shear, k = vertical shear).

From here, I suggest creating 3 simultaneous equations from the 3 points, as linear matrices can be expressed as system of equations, to solve for your shear variables, $m \text{ and } k$.

Comment: I'm only trying to find if any shear is present, not what the coefficients of the shear are.

Comment: oh... ok, then its more simple - Yes, at one least shear is present.

Comment: I'm also looking for a general approach to any transformation matrix

Comment: There are numerous approaches. Have look the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix); they provide information on 2x2 transform matrices as well homogenous 3x3 matrices.